# Android Market is not opening on Samsung galaxy GT-P7500

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

When I try to open the Market on my Samsung Galaxy GT-P7500 it shows the following dialog:

> **Your client is out of date.  It will be automatically updated shortly.**

[image: Error message]

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: I got that one day last week. Closing the market and waiting a few minutes seemed to cure it at that time. Have you actually closed the Market (come out of it using the Back button) rather than switching away from it with the Home or Applications buttons?